# Como iniciar o componente Chips do Materialize com valores pré-definidos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

Eu tenho um app de cartões de visitas, quando o usuário cadastra um cartão tem um campo de tags que são as palavras chaves do cartão.

Ele também pode editar esse cartão, logo, pode editar as tags.

Quando ele clica em editar, eu coloco todos os dados do cartão já nos campos e aí fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aí é onde mora o problema, eu não sei pq o campo de palavras chaves fica assim, não fica igual os outros.

Aqui é onde eu crio esse campo:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">find_in_page</i> 
                        <div class="chips chips-placeholder palavras-chave" placeholder="Palavras Chave"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Aqui é onde eu insiro no campo as tags que ele adicionou para editar se quiser:

```
$(".chips").append(


`<div class="chip">
                                        ${results.rows.item(i).descricao}
                                        <i class="close material-icons">close</i>
                                    </div>`
                            );
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser? Pq ele não preenche no início do campo como os demais?

Comment: Muito provavelmente pq seu CSS está escrito para atingir a tag `input` e não a tag `div`, na verdade eu nunca vi uma div com `placeholder=" "`. Mas só posso te dar certeza se é isso mesmo se vc postar o seu CSS completo... Mas tenho fortes suspeitas que seja isso que falei

Comment: Você deve estar inicializando o campo com `.chips()` antes de inserir os valores. Por que Você não utiliza a coluna `data` do [inicializador](https://materializecss.com/chips.html) para inserir os dados iniciais?

Comment: @hugocsl vou verificar meu css.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss como pode ter um número x de tags, eu insiro dentro de um for, e quando tentei fazer com o data ele não insere todos, insere somente o último valor do laço de repetição.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ou então ele insere todos os valores em uma só tag.

Comment: Outro ponto que corrobora para a suspeita é que um elemento `div` não recebe a pseudo classe `focus`, ou seja, o evento de `foco` não funciona com div... Se for isso mesmo me fala que posso bolar uma resposta com mais detalhes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Inicializando o campo antes de inserir os dados

Você está inicializando o campo com `$('.chips').chips();` antes de inserir os valores, desta forma o Materialize não irá reconhecer os valores que adicionar posteriormente. Veja:

```js
$('.chips').chips();

const itens = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];

for (let item of itens) {
  $(".chips").append(
    `<div class="chip">
       ${item}
       <i class="close material-icons">close</i>
     </div>`
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="chips"></div>
```

> Perceba que adicionando elementos após inicializar o campo o mesmo não fica funcional. Você não consegue excluir os itens adicionados pressionando o X, pois o Materialize não reconhece os elementos como valores do campo.

### Inicializando com os dados

Mas o próprio chip do Materialize permite você informar os dados iniciais do campo, você não precisa reinventar a roda, basta você utilizar o campo `data` passado à função `chips`:

```js
const itens = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];

$('.chips-initial').chips({
  data: itens.map(it => ({tag: it}))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="chips chips-initial"></div>
```

### Utilizando a função `addChip`

Outra alternativa é utilizar o método `addChip` do Materialize para adicionar os elementos:

```js
$('.chips').chips();

const itens = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];

for (let item of itens) {
  $(".chips").chips('addChip', {tag: item});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="chips"></div>
```

Comment: Sabe me dizer se a versão do Jquery interrompe alguma coisa?
typeError: $(...).chips is not a function.

o meu é 3.3.1

Comment: @Tiffany talvez você não esteja usando o Materialize pelo jQuery. Como inicializou o campo? Por `M.Chips.init`?

Comment: Não, só adicionei :
  $('.chips').chips(); /só que esse da o erro

$('.chips').material_chip('data');
            
$('.chips').material_chip();

Comment: @MFT Isso parece ser de uma versão antiga do Materialize. Algum motivo em especial para não estar utilizando a mais recente?

Comment: Não, como estou utilizando jquery foi a maneira que vi na documentação.